# Get cutted JSON in query

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in db which constains `JSON` values like:

```
{"key-1": "val-1", "key-2": "val-2", "key-3": "val-3"}
```

By query like..

```
SELECT column->>'key-1' FROM table;
```

I can get my `val-1`.

Is there a way to get `value` **with** `key` as `JSON` in `sql` query from already existed `JSON` value?

I want to get result like:

```
{"key-1": "val-1"}
```

from

```
{"key-1": "val-1", "key-2": "val-2", "key-3": "val-3"}
```

using sql query.

Comment: No, sir. Result should be one column with `{"key-1": "val-1"}` look like values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to get the key/value pair and assemble that back into a single JSON value:

```
select jsonb_build_object(j.k, j.v)
from the_table t, jsonb_each(t.json_col) as j(k,v)
where j.k = 'key-1'
  and ... more conditions ...;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/VGSX43955

Answer (score 3):

Use ampersand operator, `&`, e.g.,

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9izCEH75JhwVDvsGvsZomG/0

```
with the_table as
(
    select '{"key-1": "val-1", "key-2": "val-2", "key-3": "val-3"}'::jsonb as d
)
select d & 'key-1' as j from the_table
```

Output:

```
| j                 |
| ----------------- |
| {"key-1":"val-1"} |
```

Just kidding :) Create a function that extracts the desired key value pair, and then create your own user-defined operator for it.

```
create or replace function extract_one_jsonb(j jsonb, key text)
returns jsonb
as
$$ 
    select jsonb_build_object(key, j->key)
$$ language sql;



create operator & (
  leftarg = jsonb,
  rightarg = text, 
  procedure = extract_one_jsonb
);
```

Of course you can just use a function, or if creating a user-defined operator is not an option:

```
with the_table as
(
    select '{"key-1": "val-1", "key-2": "val-2", "key-3": "val-3"}'::jsonb as d
)
select extract_one_jsonb(d, 'key-1') as j from the_table
```

Output:

```
| j                 |
| ----------------- |
| {"key-1":"val-1"} |
```

If extracting a key value pair from jsonb is being done many times, it's desirable to give an operator for it, e.g., `&`. Postgres is pretty flexible when you want to create your own operator, this can be created too: `->>>`.

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9izCEH75JhwVDvsGvsZomG/1

```
create operator ->>> (
  leftarg = jsonb,
  rightarg = text, 
  procedure = extract_one_jsonb
);
```

Output:

```
| j                 |
| ----------------- |
| {"key-1":"val-1"} |
```

`->>` is already used by Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html

You can create `'->>>'` instead. `->>>` looks more like an extractor operator than ampersand `&`. Besides it looks good even you stick it to the source field (that is without spaces)

```
with the_table as
(
    select '{"key-1": "val-1", "key-2": "val-2", "key-3": "val-3"}'::jsonb as d
)
select d->>>'key-1' as j from the_table
```

Tried the following, it works too, looks like a scissor (for cutting): `%>`

```
select d%>'key-1' as j from the_table
```